# Composer REST server custom auth

Tags: passport.js, hyperledger-composer

I need to enable authentication on my REST server, but I have some troubles in understanding,I think.

So, if I use some custom strategy, I need to take some credentials and checked it on some data-base, and if it's right credentials, return some token which user will use later.

Am I right? If yes, how can I connect my database and how data must look like for rest-server understanding?

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn how to create custom passport strategy. If you want to validate the credentials stored in some database then, I think you might find a passport strategy for that database. You just need to provide correct COMPOSER_PROVIDERS arguments (you can check with the documentation of the passport strategy) and that's it. And I dont think rest server has anything to do with the way data (credentials) are stored in your database. It's the passport strategy which checks for your credentials.

Comment: Yes but how can strategy know that it's right credentials? I try to look for right COMPOSER_PROVIDERS arguments, but I need to write my own function that will handle data, and I don't know where I should declare and how can I require this...

Comment: You need to pass username and password as variables. Those variables will be declared in your custom strategy and in COMPOSER_PROVIDERS. You can use passport-custom to create your own passport strategy. Just download it from npm and follow some tutorials.